# HMVC vs MVC in Codeigniter

Tags: php, model-view-controller, authentication, codeigniter

I read about HMVC and is still not exactly sure how it can be useful... If i have a directory listing websites where visitors can comment on the listings, will HMVC make it easier to implement a login/members function? If so, how?

*How I got to find out about MVC is because in my directory project I am working on right now, I have not figured out a way to organize the code to allow login features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"login features" aren't really related to "MVC" or the related "HMVC" really at all.

You can implement login features with out either of these.

MVC and HMVC are just widely accepted schools of thought on the proper way to organize code into layers.

to start in on login features you should learn about sessions and maybe get started on one of the many basic php login tutorials available on the web to understand the basics.

***BUT, DO NOT STOP THERE, AS SECURITY IN THESE TUTORIALS IS COMPROMISED FOR EASE OF UNDERSTANDING***